# Typescript how to export type of class that is returned from class factory

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that returns a class. The class is defined in the function and the definition is dependent on input to the function. I am using [typescript mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#how-does-a-mixin-work) . I have created a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBLEGB2ARYFHAE2BwGMNgBnAHgBU4BeOAbwF8A%20ZuHYAdzgAKAHRiAhlADm1AFxxxORAG0AugEpm3egG4AUHvIAbcdWpwA8lAxTcbPXF7iAtsHnUY1nFJ4AiaDa4vnrsBkgo6Fi4AIwERKQUVOYsmNj4hGQJlDS0VoE4nPoAZgCuFDAYEDjoAJIAGjUActEMAEKmqKAwmeapMXGZZNnUnELt1G5w9OPA6qwOcFDAMCVQ1camvfVN0QDCJmZwXT3CMwq9UTixGSRDSXMLjuRVHlAl5DDQQmBQEGByCiUD0cILg1BKKCg31%20-3U%20lBTxeECMwBERggUiEAHI0A1mli4Y5HnBQo5QqE9OFUH0cAAmAa3RI0Hg0hlZJK5ay2aoAMlqeL2BxGxTKH0q1TQ20atLaHSOIG6JAuaXpN3ZNFGM3k0w6wMWy1W6yF-KatP2m3liuI5jGctMkRVbLuND1iJwr3enyhPz%20AMUiFdIPBkOhvrhxLd1GRqPRmKxpCgYAJOiJoNJJJCBme7vgkrqAFE8CypbShHmdkI8tz1OG9EA) that clearly demonstrates the issue.

```
function MIXIN1<TBase extends Mixin1Dependencies>(Base: TBase){
  return class MIXIN1Class extends (Base as Mixin1Dependencies){
    constructor(props: any){
      super(props);
      console.log('MXIN1');  
    }
  }
}
type Mixin2Dependencies = MixinDependencies<Origin & MIXIN1Class>;
```

I am trying to use `MIXIN1Class` type definition in the definition of `Mixin2Dependencies`. Is there any way to expose the inner `MIXIN1Class` ? or achieve similar behavior I have tried using `implements` with separate interfaces but becomes very redundant.

Comment: `MIXIN1` is a class factory. Its return type depends on the type argument passed as `TBase` upon each call to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `ReturnType` utility type.

Try `ReturnType<typeof MIXIN1>`, which should result in `MIXIN1Class` from your example.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype

Comment: `ReturnType<MIXIN1>` errors: 'MIXIN1' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MIXIN1'?

Comment: @kevzettler Did you try `ReturnType<typeof MIXIN1>`?

Comment: @spender yes I believe it is the correct answer to the general question but it throws a bunch of other errors with the MIXIN implementation

Comment: @spender yeah, right, added the `typeof` to the original answer, thanks